# PyQt - how to overlay a rectangle on an image

Tags: python, pyqt, label, draw, rectangles

After displaying an image on a PyQt label, I want to draw a rectangle on top of the displayed image. Note that I don't mean 'draw' as in where the user 'draws' a rectangle on the image, but I mean that I just want to create a rectangle on top of the image. I have the equivalent code for matplotlib axes but I'm not sure how to do the same thing in PyQt.

```
# Create Figure/Axes Instance
figure,axes = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
axes.imshow(imageRGB)

# Draw Rectangle
axes.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((50,50),100,100,fill=False,edgecolor='red'))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# convert image file into pixmap
self.pixmap_image = QtGui.QPixmap(self.filename)

# create painter instance with pixmap
self.painterInstance = QtGui.QPainter(self.pixmap_image)

# set rectangle color and thickness
self.penRectangle = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
self.penRectangle.setWidth(3)

# draw rectangle on painter
self.painterInstance.setPen(self.penRectangle)
self.painterInstance.drawRect(xPos,yPos,xLen,yLen)

# set pixmap onto the label widget
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.setPixmap(self.pixmap_image)
self.ui.label_imageDisplay.show()
```

Comment: In the code above, we can use `self.penRectangle.setWidth(3)` to change the border thickness.

Comment: @Radha Saraf, I know its been years, but I am stuck at this point. Is there a way that I could make this rectangle selectable/clickable so that some name can be assigned to this rectangle. Thanks in advance.